# Problems installing and using Mysql-proxy in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, proxy, lua

I have be stuck in this problem for over a week. I want to install mysql-proxy in ubuntu 16.04. I first downloaded [Mysql-proxy0.8.5](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/proxy/)
source code and use ./autogen.sh to generate Makefile. But I get the error:

```
 tests/unit/Makefile.am:97: warning: source file         
 '$(top_srcdir)/src/network_mysqld_type.c' is in a subdirectory,
 tests/unit/Makefile.am:97: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
```

I tried to add [AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/120)
but it did not work. Adding [AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects](http://darmawan-salihun.blogspot.com/2015/09/makefileam-option-subdir-objects-is.html) in Makefile.am do not work for me either. So I am not able to install mysql-proxy0.8.5 in ubuntu16.04 from source code.

I also tried to use the compiled version [mysql-proxy-0.8.5-linux-glibc2.3-x86-64bit.tar.gz](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/proxy/) and wrote a simple mysql-proxy.cnf file:

```
[mysql-proxy]
plugins = proxy
event-threads = 4
proxy-lua-script = /home/casualet/tutorial-rewrite.lua 
proxy-address = 192.168.56.1:3307
proxy-backen-addresses = localhost:3306
```

and I give mysql-proxy.cnf  chmod 0660; 
I used the command ./mysql-proxy --defaults-file=./mysql-proxy.cnf
The proxy starts correctly, and I get:

**2016-10-25: (critical) plugin proxy 0.8.5 started**

when I used mysql client to connect to the proxy,  I got:

**we got a normal query: select @@version_comment limit 1** 
in the proxy and

**Welcom to the MySQL monitor. Command end with ; or \g** in the client side.

However, when I issued command **show databases;** nothing happened, and the client got stuck. I thought tutorial-rewrite.lua may not suffice so I switch to another lua file, but I could still not execute my commands.

So, Do anyone have experience installing and using mysql-proxy in ubuntu?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem. Just change the version of MySQL Client to **5.5.52** instead of using the default **5.7.15** in ubuntu 16.04.

There is so little related information online about how to use mysql-proxy, which makes me think that mysql-proxy is rarely used in production. I hope this post may help others facing similar problems.:)